# Select from SQLite with Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I try to deal with SQLite database on Qt 4.5.3 on Linux. I've already created the databsae.

Then, I try to perform select on Qt:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(filename); // Here is FULL path to the database. I've checked it twice :)
bool ok = db.open();
qDebug() << db.tables();

QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("select * from lessons");
qDebug() << query.size();
qDebug() << query.isSelect();
qDebug() << query.isValid();
```

But debug console says:

```
("lessons", "weeklessons", "weeks") 
-1 
true 
false
```

Why it's select nothing? What I have doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that .size() doesn't work with Sqlite :( That is why You have -1.

Answer (score 9):

The isValid() method returns true if the query is positionned on a valid record, but after calling exec(), it isn't : you have to move to a valid record first, for example with query.first() or query.next().
See Qt docs : http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qsqlquery.html

The size() returning -1 doesn't mean there is no result : SQLite is one of the databases for which the size of the query is not directly available (look in the documentation for QSqlDriver::hasFeature()). You can check that rows are returned and find the size with a loop and query.next().

Depending on what you want to do with the result of your select, you could also use QSqlQueryModel instead of QSqlQuery.

Comment: That looks like the issue. @vas3k in general you should check the return value of exec() to see wether the execution of the query succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

In your "QSqlQuery query;" declaration, you have to specify the database connection, e.g. "QSqlQuery query(db)"

Answer (score 1):

Given that your program reports that the query is invalid, have a look at the error message as follows:

```
QDebug() << query.lastError().text();
```

This should help you in debugging the problem.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, yes I know. But it output an empty string (just one space): ("lessons", "weeklessons", "weeks") 
" " 
-1

Comment: Are you sure the query actually works? Try it from the SQLite prompt. Maybe adding a semi-colon at the end of your query might help? Finally, I would try getting the SQLite example that is shipped with Qt to work.

Comment: Yes it works in my SQLite Viewer: http://lh3.ggpht.com/_hyIyDtqe5N0/S4KNBpfapeI/AAAAAAAAAU0/3MEliEIy8G4/sqlite2.png
Adding semicolon didn't helps too. And where can I find Qt SQLite examples? I found only MySQL.

Comment: This one for example: http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/sql-sqlwidgetmapper.html

It uses an in memory SQLite database, but it should be easy to rewrite the example to use an SQLite database from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about Qt, I was asking myself one question: How does the `QSqlQuery` know which connection to use. Looking that up in the manual revealed that there are basically two possibilities to execute a query:

1. `query = db.exec("select * from lessons");`
   Using the database connection, and [executing](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qsqldatabase.html#exec) from there.
2. `QSqlQuery query( db );`
   Constructing the query using the [existing database](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-3) and then executing the query:
   `query.exec("select * from lessons");`

**edit:** After reading a bit more, it seems that default connections are supported, so your example should work…

Could you try passing the query as the constructor's value instead? Maybe it works then.

```
QSqlQuery query("select * from lessons");
```

Comment: Qt makes it as "default connection". Yes, of course I tried to do this way. Nope, same errors.

db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(filename);
bool ok = db.open();
qDebug() << db.tables();
QSqlQuery query = db.exec("select * from lessons");
qDebug() << query.size();

output:
("lessons", "weeklessons", "weeks") 
-1

Comment: And I tried to add query to constructor's value. Same errors, don't work too. Very strange :(

Answer (score 0):

This can give you a answer:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/7904-Is-there-any-other-reason-why-QSqlQuery-size%28%29-returns-1

Comment: Answers here are considered best if they don't only provide a link (however helpful that may be) but also explain the reasons of the problem or describe a solution. You can always edit your answers to improve them.