# QtSQL + Sqlite and support for .size() function?

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt4, qtsql

I'm wondering does QtSql + Sqlite support QSqlQuery::size() function?

Comment: I know its not supported. Maybe there is an alternative driver for QtSql that supports it ?

Comment: I don't think so, because the SQlite API does not provide this information (see http://winmerge.org/ and http://sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)

Comment: True, C/C++ API doesn't provide it. But look -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php . How can PHP folks do it, if its not possible ? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does't. SQLite is one of the databases for which the size of the query is not directly available. **BTW**: A Google-query for "qt sqlite QSqlQuery size" had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311218/select-from-sqlite-with-qt) StackOverflow question as first answer.

Comment: Well I googled it for a while and couldn't find anything precise. Anyway thx for answer. Franky I think its strange, sqlite api for PHP has num_rows function.

Comment: I ran that search today and first result was for *this* question.

Comment: Thanks for this info  :-)

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't. However, you can use last() and at() together to get the result.

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.exec("select * from table");
q.last();
qDebug() << q.at() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with SQLite and Qt.

As a solution I used

```
if (query.next())
{
}
```

to identify the query returns values or not.

But be careful it directs you to the first record. And if you need the no of records exactly, then this is not a solution.