# QtSqlQuery next/first returns false

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I have what I think is a very simple case, but I don't understand why it fails.

Database used is sqlite3, linux platform. Qt 5.3.

I have this table: `CREATE TABLE db_info (name TEXT, value TEXT);`

Containing this data (output from sqlite3 client):

```
version|1
created|2015-01-16 11:06:12
```

Yes, it's very simple.

The purpose is to check if the DB is created with another version of the application. So I compare the version in the DB with a compiled constant in the code.

Thus, during startup, I do this (trimmed for brevity):

```
_db = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "mydb"));
_db->setDatabaseName(dbFile);
_db->open();

QSqlQuery query(*_db);
query.prepare("SELECT value FROM db_info WHERE name = 'version' AND value = :version");
query.bindValue(":version", DB_VERSION);
query.exec();
if(query.first())
  // same version
else
  // some other version
```

Not very complicated stuff...
Now to the specific problem:

- `_db->open()` returns `true`
- `query.prepare()` returns `true`
- `query.isSelect()` returns `true`
- `query.exec()` returns `true`

After `exec()`:

- `query.isActive()` returns `true`
- `query.size()` returns `-1`
- `query.first()` or `query.next()` returns `false`

What could be the problem?
According to the dox (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#first), `first()` returns false if the query is not active or it's not a select, so that can't be it. 
But I guess, since `size()` returns -1 there definitely is something amiss somewhere...

I've tried adding some calls to `lastError()` but it's always empty. Both from `query` and from `_db`. It there some other means of getting some mesages from the database, or driver or some such?

I've also tried removing the `WHERE` clause. No difference.

Running the exact same query in the `sqlite3` client works fine.

Comment: Note that SQLite does not report the size of the query, so `size()` returning -1 is expected.

Comment: Is the value of DB_VERSION what you expect it should be?

Comment: Hmm... after trying different things, adding a lot of tracing and checks, it suddenly works. And still works after removing aforementioned traces and checks... :-|  I don't know what caused it, and probably never will. This question may be removed.

Comment: @GB: yep, it has never changed. It's just a `static const int DB_VERSION = 1;` at the top of the same file.
I kind of suspect that the boolean algebra got the better of me somewhere, and not a problem with the usage of Qt...

Comment: @pajaja: What do you mean?  It does/should return the number of rows returned by a `SELECT` query. "Returns the size of the result (number of rows returned), or -1 if the size cannot be determined or if the database does not support reporting information about query sizes.". So I'm guessing the second reason, i.e. unknown.

Comment: Yes, SQLite does not support reporting information about query sizes. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373184/qtsql-sqlite-and-support-for-size-function

Comment: Ah! That confirms it. I didn't think to look at the sqlite API directly. I kind of assumed it supported it. Thanks for the link.