# Qt SQL - Configuring Connection to Database

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qtsql

I have given up on trying to configure the MYSQL driver for the Qt 5.0 library, I am going to use the only driver currently available to me - "QSQLITE".

I have been trying to get this working for quite some time and have tried everything mentioned in similar posts:
[Select from SQLite with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311218/select-from-sqlite-with-qt)

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setHostName(SQL_SERVER);
db.setPort(SQL_PORT);
db.setDatabaseName(SQL_DATABASE);
db.setUserName(SQL_USER);
db.setPassword(SQL_PASS);
bool dbSuccess = db.open();
QList<QString> deviceNames;
QString deviceName;
qDebug() << db;
if(dbSuccess){
    QSqlQuery query;
    qWarning("We made it into the DB");
    query.exec("SELECT device_name FROM tbl_device");
    while (query.next() ){
        qDebug() << query.value(1).toString();
       // deviceNames.append(deviceName);
        //qDebug() << "Test: "<< deviceName;
    }
}
else if(!db.open()){
    qWarning("Database failed to load!");
}
```

Where SQL_Server = 192.168.1.100

I get the following qDebug output from the application:

```
QSqlDatabase(driver=""QSQLITE"", database=""homelogic"", host=""hendrenserver"", port=3306, user=""homelogic"",      open=true) 
We made it into the DB
```

The output suggests that the database connection is valid, however if I change the servername to something completely false such as "xlkcjox" or other random keys - I get the same output. What am I missing here? I feel like this should be relatively easy.

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the sqlite driver for qt, the database name is a file on your disc, regardless of the host name. This is how sqlite works. It needs no host just a filename.

Comment: Okay I was confused with PHP where I use sqli_ACTION, in which case you still have to setup the connection to the database.

Comment: To connect to an external SQL server, I must configure the SQL driver correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am revisiting this question to share a very helpful link that I came across today. I reached a solution using Qt 4.8.4 and QODBC driver. Due to a need to use QSerialPort and project bugs, I updated to 5.0.1 today. When working on rebuilding my ODBC plugin, I found this link: http://seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows. 
Within 20 minutes I had what I originally wanted, the QMYSQL driver, working. I hope this helps others!